# Do users need to log off every day?

Tags: lightning

Our system admin claims that users should log out each day to ensure they are not getting errors such as pop up blockers and system displaying Classic screen when they are using Lightning interface.

Is this true?

Answer (score 2):

It is not true but it is not a good practice as well. You can set timeout at org level in session setting. in

```
SET UP - > SESSION SETTING
```

Can set timeout value there, you have the ability to override that for each profile.

If any user kept their browser open and try to do anything they will be redirected to the login screen. I will recommend enabling "Force logout on session timeout" It will ensure auto logout happen in case user kept their browser open a good documentation can be found [here](http://Force%20logout%20on%20session%20timeout)

To enable "Force logout on session timeout" Check the checkbox "Force logout on session timeout" under `Setup -> Session Settings.`

POP-UP blocker stored in browser setting it has no relation with user logging out or not.